# How can an integer be handled like an array as an in-out parameter?

Tags: c

I'm a Swift programmer using C code in a project and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how the `kRing` function (below) works from the Uber H3 library (https://github.com/uber/h3/blob/master/examples/neighbors.c). `H3Index` is a 64-bit integer, that's all you need to know.

```
H3Index indexed = 0x8a2a1072b59ffffL;
int k = 2;
int maxNeighboring = maxKringSize(k);
H3Index* neighboring = calloc(maxNeighboring, sizeof(H3Index));

kRing(indexed, k, neighboring);

for (int i = 0; i < maxNeighboring; i++) {
    if (neighboring[i] != 0) {
        // whoa, neighboring is now magically an array, it was just an integer
    }
}
```

From Uber's documentation:

```
void kRing(H3Index origin, int k, H3Index* out);
```

> > Output is placed in the provided array in no particular order. Elements of the output array may be left zero, as can happen when crossing a pentagon.

But the output is an in-out parameter (that's what we call them in Swift, don't know what they're called in C) that's an integer type, not an array type.

Documentation on the function: https://h3geo.org/#/documentation/api-reference/traversal

Comment: `H3Index* neighboring`  and "neighboring is now magically an array" --> No it is a pointer. `neighboring` was never an integer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But it was pointing to an integer and it ended up being an array. This is how C works?

Comment: `H3Index* neighboring` is a pointer in the calling function.  _pointing to an integer_ is not an integer, but a pointer.   In function`kRing()`, `neighboring` is still a pointer.  The syntax `neighboring[i]` might look like `neighboring` is an array, but it is a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C an `int*` (int pointer) is just an address that points to an `int`. It can be used as an array:

```
int array[10];
int oneInt;

void someFunc(int* ip)
{
...
}

someFunc(array);
someFunc(&oneInt);
/* are both valid calls */
```

In the above example the person calling `someFunc` needs to know whether the pointer is being treated as a single int or an array (and if an array: how many elements ?).

This seems to be handled in the API you've given:

```
H3Index* neighboring = calloc(maxNeighboring, sizeof(H3Index));
/* gives you a pointer to an array of maxNeighboring indexes */

kRing(indexed, k, neighboring);
/* calls kRing and passes your array. kRing can use parameter "k" to 
   figure out how many elements it can play with 
*/

for (int i = 0; i < maxNeighboring; i++) { .. }
/* zeros each element in the array.
   Kind of weird. You just called kRing to populate the array and now you're
   zeroing it all out ? Seems the call to kRing was redundant in the first
   place ? 
*/
```

Comment: So C doesn't care if the types don't match, as long as there is ample memory allocated for the out parameter?

Comment: What do you mean the types don't match?

Comment: `out` is `H3Index*` which means, as far as I understand C, pointer to a property of type `H3Index` (which is an integer). However, the function assigns it a value of type array (of integers, or `[H3Index]`). In Swift, this kind of type-mismatching is invalid and would not even compile. In C, however, this is OK? You can point to an integer, pass that pointer to a function, and that function can assign that pointer (which is pointing to an integer) a value of a different type (i.e. an array of integers)?

Comment: So in C there is no definitive array type?

Comment: There is no actual array type. `int array[10]` is as close as you get. Once you start looking at it as just an `int*` you can't do "normal" array things like figuring out the size (hence needing to either pass it in or pass some other value we can use to figure it out).

Comment: The function doesn't "assign it a value of type array".  You pass the function a pointer, and the function makes changes to the addressed memory.

Comment: @John3136 --  `int array[10]` _is an array type_; C does have an actual array type, but there is constant misleading misinformation about C only having pointers that confuses learners and leads to many confused questions on SO. An array is not a pointer, and `int array[10]` is not an `int *`. Try `printf("array int[10]: %zu bytes\npointer int *: %zu bytes\n",  sizeof (int[10]), sizeof (int *));` to see that they are _not_ the same type. Arrays decay to pointers in most circumstances, but they are not pointers.

Comment: @exnihilo I know that, but they are not arrays like a Java/Swift guy might expect (e.g. no ".length"). Unfortunately the confused questions in SO aren't likely to disappear any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

In the posted code, `neighboring` is a pointer to `H3Index`. With the expression `neighboring[i]`, `neighboring` is not an integer type, but is still a pointer type; yet `neighboring[i]` does have type `H3Index`. The confusion seems to be around the use of array subscripting here.

Pointers and arrays are distinct types in C, but array subscripting can be used with pointers. The C Standard offers [§6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator [] is that **E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))**. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

That is, array subscripting is equivalent to pointer arithmetic. In the posted code, the array subscript expression `neighboring[i]` is equivalent to the pointer arithmetic expression `*(neighboring + i)`.

Note that "*...if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object)...*" does not mean that a pointer to the initial element of an array is equivalent to that array. Arrays and pointers are distinct types, which can be seen with, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Array of 20 ints: %zu bytes\n", sizeof (int [20]));
    printf("Pointer to int: %zu bytes\n", sizeof (int *));

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this outputs:

```
Array of 20 ints: 80 bytes
Pointer to int: 8 bytes
```

Here, with 4 byte `int`s, an array of 20 `int`s takes up 80 bytes, but a pointer to an `int` only takes up 8 bytes. These are two distinct types with two different sizes.

With an actual array (say, defined as `int arr[20] = {0};`), `arr[i]` must behave as the expression `*(arr + i)`, where the array identifier `arr` has *decayed* to a pointer to the first element of the array `arr[]`. Array expressions (i.e., expressions with an array type) decay to pointers to the first element of the array in most circumstances, and they do so here as well. `arr` would decay to a pointer in either expression: `arr + 1`, or in `arr[i]` (in this case `arr` is a *postfix expression* followed by a *postfix operator*).

There are a few circumstances under which an array expression will *not* decay to a pointer: if the array expression is an operand to the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` address operator, or if the array expression is a string literal used to initialize another array [§6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). Postfix array subscripting is not one of these cases.

This all means that array subscripting applied to an array is equivalent to array subscripting applied to a pointer to the first element of that array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[20] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Note: this will not work for `int *ptr = &arr`;
    //       that would have type int (*)[20],
    //       i.e, pointer to array of 20 `ints`.
    int *ptr = &arr[0];

    printf("arr[2] = %d\n", arr[2]);
    printf("ptr[2] = %d\n", ptr[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the expressions `arr[2]` and `ptr[2]` are equivalent (and both expressions have type `int` in this case). But by the same token, in the OP posted code, `neighboring[i]`, where `neighboring` is just a pointer to `H3Index`, behaves as if `neighboring` were an array of `H3Index` values, yet `neighboring` is *not* such an array.